# How to remove the cufon script from Dzonia Lite theme

Tags: php, theme-development, functions

I am using Dzonia Lite theme in my website. When I try to remove the cufon script from my functions.php file the sliders that were present in the website are not working.

Colud anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue?

## scripts in my functions.php

```
function inkthemes_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-ddsmoothmenu', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/ddsmoothmenu.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-slides', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/slides.min.jquery.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-jcarouselite', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-confu-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/cufon-yui.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-quicksand-confu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mank-sans.cufonfonts.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
    } elseif (is_admin()) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't load those scripts, then the theme won't work because it depends on them. Why do you want to remove the scripts?

Comment: @gdaniel I don't want to use cufon in my website

Comment: I am guessing that the custom.js script has references to cufon - so if you remove it, then custom.js won't work. If you get errors, it would help to for us to see what erros you are getting. If you are using firefox or chrome to view your website, you can use the debugger that comes with those browser to find the errors.

Comment: This is the error i am getting  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/digitals/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dzonia-lite/functions.php on line 55

Answer (score 1):

You can remove scripts with [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script):

```
function wpse99450_remove_cufon() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'inktheme-confu-ui' );
    // inktheme-confu-ui is the script's handle, according to your posted code
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse99450_remove_cufon', 20 );
// set priority to '20' so it will run later than the default
```

But be careful -- as @gdaniel pointed out, if the theme depends on `cufon`, *you will break things*.

Comment: ok i will  check this

Comment: When I add this code the blog is dissappearing.

Comment: Disappearing as in showing just a blank page?  The PHP code validates, so there aren't any syntax errors.

Comment: Error I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/digitals/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dzonia-lite/functions.php on line 55

Comment: Does the parse error go away if you comment out my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove or comment out the line:

```
wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-confu-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/cufon-yui.js", array('jquery'));
```

Update:

You would also need to remove or comment out:

```
wp_enqueue_script('inkthemes-quicksand-confu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mank-sans.cufonfonts.js', array('jquery'));
```

Which is the  font cufon is trying to load.

Custom.js probably makes references to those two lines. You should see something related like this below in your custom.js file.

```
Cufon.replace('#cufon-area');
```

If custom.js has any cufon functions then you will get errors, because it can't find those functions.

Comment: That didn't work